# Google Chrome: "Open a specific page or set of pages" - Opens additional tab pages

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I configured Google Chrome to start with this set of tab pages and then pinned all of them.

[image: 2]

When Google Chrome starts after closing all tab pages except the first six, this set of tab pages is opened:

[image: 1]

I'm not sure why, so I don't know which further information to provide, but is there a way to fix tabs being opened additionally to the predefined set?

Answer (score 0):

You have the first 6 tab pages pinned.
So when chrome opens, it opens your pinned tabs first followed by a new tab.
A new tab is your case the configuration above.
SO: You should unpin those tabs, which can be a hassle (because sometimes chrome still thinks they're pinned), and then try again.

Comment: Usually, the 6 tab pages satisfy this configuration and no additional tabs should be opened. For example: I close all tabs, so all 6 tabs get opened. I pin all of them, close Chrome again and still, one or two tab pages get opened as duplicates.

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't have those tabs pinned if you want them to be opened by the new tab configuration. Not sure why it doesn't open all tabs in your new tab configuration thought.

Comment: I don't see how pinned/not pinned is an attribute to what Chrome opens upon restart. Yet, it's inconsistent...

Comment: Chrome opens in steps: 1) Open pinned tabs, 2) Open new tab (that configuration)